# How do I use an extended generic type's type in a class?

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

Say I have some classes as follows:

```
class A { }

class B<TA extends A> { }

class C<TB extends B<? extends A>> {
    TA varOfTypeTA; // this throws an error obviously
}
```

**How can I define the type of `varOfTypeTA` to be whatever TB's TA is?**

I know I can define it as `A varOfTypeTA`, but I want it to be of type `TA` not `A`.

I tried forcing it to define TA with `class C<TB extends B<TA extends A>>` so I can use `TA`, but this throws a syntax error.

To clarify, if I then define these classes:

```
class Horse extends A { }

class HorseHerd extends B<Horse> { }

class HorseHerder extends C<HorseHerd> {
    Horse getFavoriteHorse() { return varOfTypeTA; } // varOfTypeTA defined in class C must be of type Horse, otherwise I have to cast
}
```

How can I make `varOfTypeTA` be of type `Horse`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Also declare `TA` as a generic in the same class.**

```
public class C<TA extends A, TB extends B<TA>> {
    TA varOfTypeTA;
}
```

Then you can use `TA` in your class.

```
class HorseHerder extends C<Horse, HorseHerd> {
    Horse getFavoriteHorse() { return this.varOfTypeTA; }
}
```

I was also surprised to learn that the order of the declaration doesn't seem to matter here.  While I would prefer to declare `TA` first, I have found that this code also compiles:

```
public class C<TB extends B<TA>, TA extends A> {
    TA varOfTypeTA;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the only answer. There is no way to declare it without adding it as a separate type every time?

Comment: The only way I could see that you would only need one is if you could remove `TB`.  If you could create a class `Herd<TA extends A>` that you could use for every `TA`, then you could declare `public class C<TA extends A>`, use `Herd<TA>`  instead of `TB` inside `C`, and then declare `public class HorseHerder extends C<Horse>` to extend this.

Comment: If you need to use `TA` instide `C`, then you need to declare `TA`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass both generic types. So, for example:

```
class C<TB extends B<TA>, TA extends A> {
    TA varOfTypeTA;
}

class Horse extends A {}

class HorseHerd extends B<Horse> {}

class HorseHerder extends C<HorseHerd, Horse> {
    Horse getFavoriteHorse() { return varOfTypeTA; }
}
```

Comment: Would prefer Erick Robertson approach. Using something before declaring is always confusing.   Here you make use of **TA** Type and you declare it after usage :)

Comment: @Vyncent Agreed. I'll leave this answer here to show that it can be done the other way around though.

Comment: no prob, your answer is correct, i'm just telling which approach i prefer ;)